# DataTables sorting cells containing only a glyphicon

Tags: jquery, html, sorting, datatables

I have a column that is pure glyphicons with no text. I'd like to make it sortable, right now clicking sort does nothing.

I'd like to keep it to just icons and no text, is there anyway I can assign values for sorting purposes?

Sample HTML for 1 cell:

```
<a href='#' class='toggleAdmin' data-id='123412341234' data-t='remove'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon-success'></i></a>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I added the following inside of my `<i>`:

```
<div style='display: none;'>1</div>
```

The sorting is now working without a decrease in performance.